# How to get multiple selected row value from uitableview and save multiple selected value in array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have list of states in UITableView.Now i want to select multiple row of UITableView and wanna get this selected row values in one array.how can i get this?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //NSMutableArray *arrData =[statearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"arrdata>>%@",statearray);

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [statearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

}
```

Comment: Enter transfer tableView edit mode, then save selected status

Answer (score 4):

You can call `tableview.indexPathForSelectedRows`. This will output an array with the indexpaths for all selected rows in your tableview!

This is how your code would look like in swift 3:

```
var values : [String] = []
let selected_indexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows
for indexPath in selected_indexPaths! {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    values.append((cell?.textLabel?.text)!)
}
```

After running this code the values of all selected cells should be in the `values` array.

Comment: UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *cellText = selectedCell.textLabel.text;

Comment: By this way i am getting selected row value in string.but how to get multiple selected row value in one array with comma seperater?

Comment: You can just use the `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRows` which is going to give you an array of indexpaths. Then you can make a `for loop` and loop through all indexpaths in this array and get the cell for each indexpath as you are doing it in your code and just save the results in an array.

Comment: @sp309 Did you achieve what you wanted?

Comment: No.i want every selected row value in array.how to save all that value?@Stefan Stefanov

Comment: @sp309 I just edit my answer with the code you would need in swift 3!

Comment: Please can you provide code into objective c?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135844/discussion-between-sp309-and-stefan-stefanov).

Comment: @sp309 This is a working code in Swift 3. You can translate it yourself for Objective C, I am sorry but I am not a specialist in Objective C. Since it's a working code, answering your question, can you please accept it as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

you can keep track of selected cells with below way

```
var selectedCells: [UITableViewCell] = []
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedCells.append(tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!)
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let deselectedRow = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    if(selectedCells.contains(deselectedRow!)){
        let indx = selectedCells.index(of: deselectedRow!)
        selectedCells.remove(at: indx!)
    }
}
```

Idea is to maintain array of selected cells when cell selection happens and remove cell once deselection is done

Best way is to get selected indexpaths using method

```
tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows
```

you can get the data out in an array

```
var oldArray: [NSIndexPath] = [NSIndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 0), NSIndexPath.init(row: 1, section: 0), NSIndexPath.init(row: 2, section: 0), NSIndexPath.init(row: 3, section: 0)]
var newArray: [Int] = oldArray.flatMap { ($0.row) }
```

Like if we have array in form of oldArray, We can get only rows using flatMap.

Comment: with tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows i will get the array of the sections and the rows how can i get the array of just rows ?

Comment: combination of sections and rows makes data unique, So if you want just rows, then its possible to have same row number selected in different sections, Which might become ambiguous. If you can give details, how you want your data. I might be able to help you.

Comment: I just want to have selected rows index but I will receive some thing like this [[0,0],[0,1],[0,4]] as you see I will receive index of rows But I will receive index of section But I don't want it! I want to get an array of selected rows index like this [0,1,4]

Comment: Check my answer above, which should solve your problem of getting only rows in array.

Answer (score 1):

There is default method of tableview, 
`self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows`

Which gives you an array of selected indexpaths. But you need to also set property of tableview

`self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true`

Answer (score 0):

If want back selcted rows to track,

```
NSArray *selectedRowsArray = [yourTableViewName indexPathsForSelectedRows];
```

**Answer updated**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    //the below code will allow multiple selection
    if ([yourMutableArray containsObject:indexPath])
    {
       [yourMutableArray removeObject:indexPath];
    }
    else
    {  
        [yourMutableArray addObject:indexPath];

    }
    [yourTableView reloadData];

}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    if ([yourMutableArray containsObject:indexPath])

    {

       //Do here what you wants

       if (contentArray.count > 0) {

            NSDictionary *dictObje = [contentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dictObje objectForKey:@"name"]];

       }

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else
    {

       //Do here what you wants
        if (contentArray.count > 0) {

            NSDictionary *dictObje = [contentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dictObje objectForKey:@"name"]];

       }

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    }

return cell;
}
```

Comment: I want selected all row values as objects of array.how can i get?

Comment: Friend what you mean selected all row values  exactly?

Comment: @sp309 Why exactly do you want a array structure for selected rows. `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRows` is the array os selected rows, can you be more detailed about the problem?

Comment: UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [self.tableviewState cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *cellText = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
    NSLog(@"cellText>>%@",cellText);
    
    NSArray *indexPathArray = [tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];

By using this code ,i am getting selected row value in string.but i didn't getting anything in indexPathArray.but i want all selected row value in one array.@ystack

Comment: hey man ... what are you doing yar. Still i am imagining you just wants to enable multiple selection i am gonna update answer check it if working for you.

Comment: i have already implement multiple selection in my project.now i want that selected value back in array.I have applied your code but nothing saves in yournutablearray.i want all selected value in yournutablearray.

Comment: which values you wants to fetch? & if you have that values in array why u dont access it in cellForRowAtIndexPath ?